# How to load a WTF Form class each time I hit an API endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms

I am using Flask WTF Form which relies on loading a list of vendors from an API. This vendor list will change however I found found that each time I hit the new item path, (I was expecting to recreate the NewItemForm class) the old class was loaded from memory. The vendors API path was hit just once on object creation

So I updated my code to this non functional example: I gave it my best shot, but what I would like to do is hit the Vendors API endpoint each time I hit the new inventory item path, when I create the `NewItemForm()` so that the vendors list changes each time the form is loaded. I tried doing this by creating a method.

What is the pythonic way to solve this problem?

**api.py**:

```
@inventory.route('/inventory/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_item():
    form = NewItemForm()
    form.update_vendors()
```

**form.py**:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, SelectField, DecimalField, DateField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Length, NumberRange, Optional
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea
import requests, json, os

class NewItemForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sorted_by_vendors=[('','')]

    def update_vendors(self):
        api_uri = os.environ.get('API_URL') or 'http://127.0.0.1/whiteboard_v2/v2/'
        second_url = api_uri + "api/vendors"
        second_request = requests.get(second_url)
        other_keys = second_request.json().keys()
        vendorOptions=[('','')]
        othersortedList = []
        for key in other_keys:
            vendor_tuple = (key, second_request.json()[key]['vendor_name'])
            vendorOptions.append(vendor_tuple)
            self.sorted_by_vendors = sorted(vendorOptions, key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0]))

    vendor_code = SelectField('Vendor', choices = self.sorted_by_vendors, validators = [Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Create Item')
```

**How can I load the list of vendors each time I hit the new_item endpoint, so that the vendors dropdown changes?**

Comment: You're not actually calling `update_vendors` method in `new_item`. You need to add `()` to call it like this: `form.update_vendors()`.

Comment: Thanks but I'm pretty sure my example code is fundamentally wrong. I just used it to show my intent.

Comment: The intent seems to be the right one. Are you sure you hit the `/new` route the second time? If you did than I'd be interested if the form object from the original request is the same form object of the second request (maybe Flask or  WTForms is trying to be clever with reused objects).

Comment: Well, it totally bugs out at vendor_code = SelectField('Vendor', choices = self.sorted_by_vendors, validators = [Required()]) because it does not recognize self.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you bind the field with

`vendor_code = SelectField('Vendor', choices = self.sorted_by_vendors, ...`

which binds the field's `choices` attribute at *class level* to a reference to that list, and then later on you replace `sorted_by_vendors` to reference a new list, while the `.choices` attribute still points to the old reference copy.

The simplest fix is making this change in `update_vendors()`:

`self.vendor_code.choices = sorted(vendorOptions, key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0]))`

You can also move that one out of the for loop, you only need to do it once at the end.